# How to retrieve data of a specific user in android studio using firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I have been working on an appointment booking app where a user can book appointment by choosing date and time . I have used  Java and Firebase(Firestore) for designing my app.
Here I need to retrieve the data of the specific user who has logged in and display it in my next Page(Details Page).

The data I need to display should be different for different users means if A enters and book an appointment only his details has to be visible but not B's details.

Actually i tried using

`db.collection("Documents").document(id).get()`

But it throws an error in my Notification Page where appointment Details are displayed

Please check my Cloud Firestore :

[image: Firestore]

Here is the image where the booking is done and the details gets inserted.
Here is the place where id is inserted.

[image: Data]

Notification.java

```
public class Notification extends AppCompatActivity {

/* DatabaseReference studentDbRef;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Booking> list;
*/
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<Booking> list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)  //remove top actionbar
    {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Notification.this));

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(Notification.this,list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    showData();

  /*  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    studentDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Book");

    studentDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Booking book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Booking.class);
                list.add(book);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });*/

}
private void showData(){
    db.collection("Documents").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    list.clear();
                    for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()){
                        Booking book = new Booking(snapshot.getString("id"),snapshot.getString("date"),snapshot.getString("time"),snapshot.getString("barber"));
                        list.add(book);

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Notification.this,"OOPS something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

When i book an appointment by logging in I get my data as well as another users data .Couldn't Figure it out please help. I have tried other solutions but it didnt work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I resolved it sir, Actually the error was i couldn't get specific users data who has logged in .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using :

```
FirebaseAuth fAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
String id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

While i retrieving the data i used

```
db.collection("Documents").whereEqualTo("uid",id).get() .
```

This solution really helped me out to get specific users data who has logged in